# Visual Studio 2015 Tasklist - .vbhtml TODO comments don't show

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015, comments

Is there a way to get HTML or vbhtml `TODO` comments to show up in the Visual Studio [Task List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/170k1bbs(v=vs.110).aspx)? VB and JavaScript comments show up in the task list when using something like `' TODO: some task`, but when using HTML comments or vbhtml with `@* TODO: some task *@`, it doesn't show up in the task list.

[image]

Is this because it is a block comment?

And is there a way to get the comments to show in the task list?

Comment: I found that comments in CSS files show up, but only the first line of the comment.

Comment: Vote up the suggestion https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32972119-todo-s-in-vbhtml-files-don-t-show-in-task-list.